# new File() en algunos metodos da error y en otro no

Tags: java, archivo

He visto multitud de preguntas y respuestas sobre el tema, y al final tuve que elegir el unico que me funcionaba. El problema, es que utilio las mismas intrucciones exactamente iguales en varios metodos segun su condicion, y en algunos metodos si me crea el archivo en la memoria interna, pero en algunos metodos me sale error y no me los crea. Es tan simple como el codigo, y no entiendo porque algunos si funcionana y algunos no...!?!?

```
    try {
        if(usuario!=null){
               Log.d("FileManager","user not null, usuario="+usuario);
               createLocalFileUser(this);
        } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("FileManager", "Error creando el archivo local_file_user==>"+e);
        }

    public void createLocalFileUser(Context context) throws IOException {
        Log.d("FileManager","Start createLocalFileUser!");
        File local_file_user= new File(context.getFilesDir(),"user");
        local_file_user.createNewFile();
        Log.d("FileManager","NewFile Created!");
        displayToast("Archivo local de usuario creado!");
        Log.d("FileManager","local_file_create="+ local_file_user.getAbsolutePath());
}

    Start createLocalFileUser!
    E/FileManager: Error creando el archivo local_file_user==>java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: cómo declaras usuario? cuál es el import de context? sacaste el código inicial de alguna pregunta de acá (y en dado caso de cual) ? Recuerda siempre poner un [mcve]

Comment: Probe muchos codigos de esta pagina, y este fue el unico que me funciono. El usuario es un String y el contexto, me obliga a ponerlo para que funcione el metodo porque lo requiere, sino no funciona. En File local_file_user=new File("user"); todo eran errores, con el contexto si me lo crea pero creo que el error esta en displayToast(String texto); algunas veces va y otras no. Al dar error en displayToast me saca a la excepcion. pero nose porque a veces va y otras no.

Comment: Solucionado, el error era con el Toast, añadiendo otro metodo incluyendo el context.
public void displayToast(String text){
        int duration= Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this,text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    public void displayToast(Context context, String text){
        int duration= Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context,text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }